# Most efficient algorithm to determine whether a given finite sequence is mutually distinct

Tags: algorithms

Let $a_1, \dots a_n$ be a finite sequence of elements of a set $X$.
I'm wondering what is the most efficient algorithm to determine
whether the number of elements of the set $\{a_1,\dots, a_n\}$ is $n$.
A naive one is to compare every pair $a_i, a_j$ where $i \neq j$.
Can this be improved?

Comment: At least by a factor $2$ if you compare $a_i, a_j$ only if $i < j.\;$ Is there an order on the set, i.e. can the sequence be sorted?

Comment: Comparing every pair is of order $n^2$. If you first sort the elements and then compare adjacent ones, you get the order $n \log (n)$ (the fastes order of any sorting algorithm I'm aware of). I'm not an expert in this, so maybe you can do it in another, faster way.

Comment: @gammatester As long as $X$ is countable, you can define an order.